# Fit graph into specified dimensions pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to get my graph to fit inside of the graph's dimensions (4in by 7.5in). I want the ymin of the graph to be the minimum y value of all my points and the ymax value the maximum y value for all of my points (so that my graph fits snugly but doesn't get cut off).

My graph seems to go outside of the boundaries. I've tried to use `enlargelimits=true` but it adds too much whitespace.

I've also tried `enlarge y limits={true, abs value=0.75},` and many different variations, however it doesn't appear to affect the graph at all.

I could use xmin and xmax but I have ~20 graphs, and I don't really want to change each separately.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=1,
        enlarge y limits={true, abs value=0.75},
        xlabel=Atomic Number,
        ylabel=Atomic Radius $(in$ $pm)$,
        width=7.5in,
        height=4in,
        enlargelimits = false,
        extra x ticks={1,84},
        title={\large Atomic Number vs. Atomic Radius $(in$ $pm)$}]
    \addplot[smooth,mark=none,black] plot coordinates {
(1,37.1) (2,31) (3,152) (4,112) (5,85) (6,77.2) (7,70) (8,73) (9,72) (10,71) (11,186) (12,160) (13,143) (14,117.6) (15,110) (16,103) (17,100) (18,98) (19,227) (20,197) (21,162) (22,147) (23,134) (24,128) (25,127) (26,126) (27,125) (28,124) (29,128) (30,134) (31,135) (32,122.3) (33,120) (34,119) (35,114) (36,112) (37,248) (38,215) (39,180) (40,160) (41,146) (42,139) (43,136) (44,134) (45,134) (46,137) (47,144) (48,151) (49,167) (50,140.5) (51,140) (52,142) (53,133) (54,131) (55,265) (56,222) (57,187) (58,182) (59,182) (60,181) (61,183) (62,180) (63,208) (64,180) (65,177) (66,178) (67,176) (68,176) (69,176) (70,193) (71,174) (72,159) (73,146) (74,139) (75,137) (76,135) (77,136) (78,139) (79,144) (80,151) (81,170) (82,146) (83,150) (84,168)     };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Yep, I already added it! It's the graph around x=1

Comment: MWE is meant to be the code producing it. Please check the link in my previous comment.

Comment: @alexy13: An MWE should be a complete minimal document, so something beginning with `\documentclass` that can just be copied into a new document to get a compilable `.tex` file. Otherwise everyone who wants to try and help needs to complete the file themselves, which is not a whole lot of fun.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting `enlargelimits=false`, as you've done, causes PGFPlots to adjust the limits so that all the data points are just visible. However, this does not take into account the overshooting introduced by the `smooth` style. So you'll need to adjust the limits, using something like (as you've attempted) `enlarge y limits={true, abs value=5}`. However, you *also* need to remove the `enlargelimits=false`, otherwise you'll override the setting.

I would recommend not using the `smooth` style, however: As you've noticed, it doesn't accurately represent the data due to the overshooting. Also, smoothing the data makes it seem like you have much more data than you actually do, so it's not entirely honest.